# How does MIPS assembler manage label address?

Tags: mips, mips32

#### How does MIPS's assembler labels and J type instruction work?

I am currently making a MIPS simulator using C++ and came into a big question. **How exactly does MIPS assembler manage label's and their address while on a J type instruction?**

Let's assume that we have a following code. Also let's assume that `start:` starts at `0x00400000`. Comments after code represent where the machine codes will be stored in memory.

```
start:
        andi $t0, $t0, 0     # 0x0040 0000
        andi $t1, $t1, 0     # 0x0040 0004
        andi $t2, $t2, 0     # 0x0040 0008
        addi $t3, $t3, 4     # 0x0040 000C
loop:
        addi $t2, $t2, 1     # 0x0040 0010
        beq $t2, $t3, exit   # 0x0040 0014
        j loop               # 0x0040 0018

exit:
        addi $t0, $t0, 1000  # 0x0040 002C
```

As I am understanding right at the moment, `j loop` expression will set PC as `0x0040 0010`.

When J type instruction uses **32 bits** and with MSB **6 bits** as its opcode, it only has **26 bits** left to represent address of instruction. Then how is it possible to represent **32 bit** address system using only **26 bits**?

With the example above, it can represent `0x00400010` with only 24bits. However, in references, text segment is located from `0x00400000` to `0x10000000` which needs 32bit to represent.

I have tried to understand this using [MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/download.htm) simulator, however it just represents `j loop` as `j 0x00400010` which seems nonsense to me since `0x00400010` is 32 bits.

#### My current guess

One of my current guesses is following.

Assembler saves the `loop:` label's address into some memory address that is reachable by 26 bits. Then when expression `j loop` is called, label `loop` is translated to the memory address that contains `0x00400010` For example, `0x00400010` is saved in some address like `0x00300000` and when `j loop` is called, `loop` is translated into `0x00300000` and it is able to get value from `0x00300000` and reach out `0x00400010`. (This is just one of my guess)

Comment: https://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-17/ass17_5.html

Comment: That solved my question. Thank you @Mat

Comment: How is it possible to represent 32 bits of address using only 26 bits? You can't. What ends up happening is that the branch operands are relative to the address of the branch instruction itself. So that `j loop` at `0x00400018` is really encoded to mean "jump 8 bytes back."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of questions here.

First, let's try to differentiate between the assembler's operation and the MIPS machine code that it generates and the processor executes.

The assembler manages labels and address in two ways.  First, it has a symbol table, which is like a dictionary, a data structure of key-value pairs where the names are keys and the addresses (that those names will refer to when the program is running) are the values in the pairs.

Second, the assembler manages the code and data sections with a location counter.  That location counter advances each time the program provides some code or data.  When new label is defined, the current location counter is then used as the address value in a new key-value pair.

The processor never sees the labels: they do not execute and they do not occupy any space in the code or data.  The processor sees only machine code instructions, which on MIPS are all 32-bits wide.  Each machine code instruction is divided into fields.  There are instruction types or formats, which on MIPS are straightforward: I-Type, J-Type, and R-Type.  These formats then define the instruction fields, and the assembler follows these encodings.  All the instruction formats share the 6-bit opcode field, and this opcode field tells the processor what format the instruction is, which fields it therefore has, and thus how to interpret and execute the rest of the instruction.

The assembler removes labels from the assembly — labels and their names do not exist in the program binary.  The label definitions themselves (`label:`) are omitted from the program binary but *usages of labels* are translated into numbers, so a machine code instruction that uses a label will have some instruction field that is numeric, and the assembler will provide a proper value for that numeric field so that the effect of the reaching or otherwise accessing what the label referred to is accomplished.  (The label is no longer in the program binary, but the code or data memory that the label referred does remain).

The assembler sets up branch instructions, `j` instructions, and `la`/`lw` instructions, using numbers that tell the processor how far forward or backward to move the program counter, or, what address some data of interest is at.  The `lw`/`la` instructions access data, and these use 2 x 32-bit instructions each holding 16 bits of the address of interest.  Between the two instructions, they put together a full 32-bit address for data access.  For branches to fully reach any 32-bit address, they would have to put together the 32-bit address in a similar manner (two instruction pair) and use an indirect/register branch.